# REQUEST_TIME in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a similar function in C# that is akin to the PHP functionality of `("$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']")`?

Comment: Something like `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: "Timestamp of the start of the request is available in $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] since PHP 5.1." - http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php.

Comment: you won't get it directly but compute it wrt to 1 Jan 1970, care to expand as what you intend to do

Answer (score 10):

The following property returns the initial timestamp of the current HTTP request:

```
HttpRequest.RequestContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
```

In an ASP.Net-Page it can be accessed through the `Request` object like this:

```
Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Is the httpContext in the RequestContext different from HttpContext.Current?

Comment: `RequestContext.HttpContext` returns a `HttpContextWrapper` with a much lighter interface than `HttpContext.Current`. The latter returns a `HttpContext` object.

Comment: Ah cool. I figured it was probably different. Will have to look into that. :)

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for your. But it's not suggesting to me can you please let me know that do i need to add extra reference for this.

Comment: It's in the System.Web namespace.

Comment: @Dennis I am using Asp.net it's already has Web namespacebut it's not working.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension method to convert a `DateTime` to a Unix timestamp (which is what I understand to be held in `REQUEST_TIME`):

```
public static class TimeTools
{
    private static readonly DateTime StartOfEpoch = 
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public static long ToUnixTime(this DateTime dt)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt64(
            (dt.ToUniversalTime() - StartOfEpoch).TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

so (borrowing from [@Dennis` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610058/request-time-in-c/7610230#7610230))

```
Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Timestamp.ToUnixTime()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) or [DateTime.UtcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx).

Comment: I think he's looking for the timestamp associated with the http request.

Comment: If you access these DateTime properties during the request, it will be the timestamp of the request. But `HttpContext.Timestamp` is probably the better option.

Comment: Just taking the timestamp at some point during the request introduces an undeterminable offset. Which may or may not be critical, depending on the actual situation, of course.